Rearrange these numbers and symbols to make a true equation
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

Rearrange these numbers and symbols to make a true equation:
2 3 4 5 + =

Attribution:  Mathigon 2019 calendar - puzzle # 4

The answer is:

 32 = 4 + 5

We know that there's something tricky because:

 If the solution is linear, two operators can only divide the equation into three pieces, and the pigeonhole principle ensures that one of those pieces is two digits.  The smallest two-digit number formed with these numbers is 23, which is considerably larger than 4 + 5.

Incidentally,

 The original calendar form of the puzzle hints at this a little more, as it writes the numbers and symbols as:

 2 3 4
 5 + =


How does the original form give a clue about the solution more?

@justhalf By presenting the symbols in that form rather than the form presented in the question, it makes clearer that rot13(gur raq erfhyg vf abg arprffnevyl whfg n erbeqrevat bs gur flzobyf jvguva gur fgevat bs grkg).
